# How to get SIP caller information under android sip library

Tags: android, sip

I have an Android application using [Android SIP library](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/connectivity/sip.html).

In receiving call part, I would like to know the caller's information like the caller account so that user can decide to answer or decline the call.

However, I can't find how to display this information.

My question is how to get **caller account/ID** of the incoming call ?

Below is my broadcast receiver to receiver incoming sip call:

```
public class IncomingCallReceiver extends BroadcastReceiver {
    public void onReceive(final Context context, Intent intent) {
        ...
        SipManager sipManager = SipManager.newInstance(this);
        ...
        SipAudioCall call = sipManager.takeAudioCall(sipIntent, listener);
        if(answerCall){
            call.answerCall(30);
        }else{
            call.endCall();
        }

    }
}
```

I have tried to parse the incoming intent. There are two extras in intent contain the followings:

android:sipCallID:

```
v=0
o=- 1458035023435 1458035023447 IN IP4 210.202.37.33
s=-
c=IN IP4 210.202.37.33
t=0 0
m=audio 13662 RTP/AVP 96 97 3 0 8 127
a=rtpmap:96 GSM-EFR/8000
a=rtpmap:97 AMR/8000
a=rtpmap:3 GSM/8000
a=rtpmap:0 PCMU/8000
a=rtpmap:8 PCMA/8000
a=rtpmap:127 telephone-event/8000
a=fmtp:127 0-15
a=direction:active
a=nortpproxy:yes
```

android:sipOfferSD:

```
300ac55ee035a105a2b11be200c63ba0@10.139.98.112
```

but, it's seems not helpful.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you posted as content of the intent seems to be the `SDP` (Session Description Protocol) offer, which contains the description of media parameters. It doesn't have the session information you seek.

Since yo have a [SipManager](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/net/sip/SipManager.html) instance, I am guessing you somehow [`createSipSession()`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/net/sip/SipManager.html#createSipSession(android.net.sip.SipProfile,%20android.net.sip.SipSession.Listener)). Once you have the session you can retrieve the [SipProfile](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/net/sip/SipProfile.html) of the peer using `getPeerProfile()` which should in turn contain the information you require.

You can also get the peer profile using `call.getPeerProfile()` if the previous doesn't work, since you also have a `SipAudioCall` object.

Comment: Thanks.  The following is what I need

`SipAudioCall call = sipManager.takeAudioCall(sipIntent, listener);`
`Nname = call.getPeerProfile().getUserName();`

Comment: @Cody glad I could help! Cheers